# Edit a single field within a map array in Firebase using JavaScript. (React-Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, react-native-firebase

In firebase I have a data structure like this:

[image]

Is a map array with some values inside it.

(Using JavaScript) For example, if I wanted to update ONLY the field "field1" of the array at position 1 without updating the entire "ArrayTest", how could I do that?

I tried a solution like this:

```
 const exampleFunction = async () => {
    const usersDocRef = firestore().collection('users').doc(docID);

    usersDocRef.update({
      'ArrayTest.1.field1': "newFoo",
    })
  }
```

But what happens is that it removes everything else from the "ArrayTest" leaving such a structure:

```
ArrayTest
    - [1]
      - field1: "NewFoo"
```

And obviously I don't want to edit or delete the rest of the structure, just a single field, how could I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you can't directly access an array by index in firestore. Although you could get around this by implementing a solution that reads the document, gets the array, updates the specific element/field, and then update the array in the document.

Here's an example:

```
const doc = await docRef.get();
const array = doc.data().array; // change `array` for the field name

// update array field
array[1].field1 = 'bar';

await docRef.update({ array });
```

Note, this example assumes that `docRef` is already defined.

This is a very basic example which you'd need to change for your requirements but it shows the basic principle.

Beware that this is also not an optimal solution as now it is costing you a read and a write just to update the field so this is more expensive both in terms of time and money. It's impossible for me to say if there's a way around your problem that avoids updating an array in the first place, so my first approach would be to first see if there's another solution you can implement, if not, use something like the example above. Hope this helps!